# How to submit a form WITHOUT clicking a submit button?

Tags: javascript

I want the form to be submitted when the user chooses one of the radio button options. I know how to do this with select fields:

```
<select name='something' onchange="this.form.submit()">
```

But how to do this with radio buttons?

Comment: `<select name='radio' onchange="this.form.submit()">`?

Comment: People don't expect radio buttons to submit forms, don't break their expectations. Just use a series of submit buttons instead of radio buttons.

Comment: maybe you should look into using ajax instead.  It might be what you are looking for.

Comment: @David his next actions might depend on the selected radio button...

Comment: @krock +1 - Take a look at scriptaculous autocomplete plugin. Though it is for autocompletion, you can either take inspiration from it or your can use it without using the autocomplete functionality...

Comment: @Jagira So what? Once the form is submitted, there is no difference between a piece of data acquired via a submit button and a piece of data acquired via a radio button. They just provide a name/value pair.

Comment: @david agreed... but if your interface demands selection then radio/check boxes might look good... again it all depends on the design...

Comment: A silk dress might look good, but it wouldn't be the right choice of clothing for an Antarctic expedition. Use the right tool for the job, then apply some CSS to make it attractive without sending people mixed signals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use onclick:

```
<input type="radio" name="something" onclick="this.form.submit()">
```

You can test for compatibility (of keyboard entry like left/right or tabbing then pressing space/enter and even keyboard only navigation plugins) using [this example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/Form-Control/AnonClickeventHandlerforRadioButtons.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Try hooking into the `onclick` event.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="radio" name="something" value="somethingvalue" onclick="this.form.submit();" />
```